# OpenGL how to properly clear back buffer

Tags: opengl, rendering

I am developing the 2D app.
In diffrent phases of the program I render to diffrent quads. so for example.
I start with
[image]

Then render to the same quad so it will turn black and render only to the thinner quad at the center
[image]

It works well, but when I will try to render one more time to the thinner quad at the center and swap buffers I get

[image]

So In area that was not rendered onto in this cycle I get old image onto the screen
As far as I understand I getit from back buffer .
But in this case glclearcolor should solve the problem , yet I tried

```
glFinish()
glFlush()
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0 , 1.0)
```

in diffrent combinations before next rendering, yet the problem -  remains every second swap buffer operation old image pop up in areas that I do not render to in current cycle.

Thanks for help !

Comment: What about [`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) (before drawing the scene)?

Comment: All this rendering of multiple passes into a single target are crying out loud for using framebuffer objects.